# pip install making ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061]

Tags: python, pip

Trying to install a package but can't and keep getting this error:

```py
pip install facebook-scrapper
Collecting facebook-scrapper
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000248EDD77B00>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',)': /simple/facebook-scrapper/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000248EDD77D68>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',)': /simple/facebook-scrapper/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000248EDD77B38>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',)': /simple/facebook-scrapper/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000248EDD77BA8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',)': /simple/facebook-scrapper/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000248EDD77518>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',)': /simple/facebook-scrapper/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement facebook-scrapper (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for facebook-scrapper
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python365\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python365\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\python365\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\python365\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\python365\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 248, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "c:\python365\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 252, in main
    pip_version_check(session)
  File "c:\python365\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\outdated.py", line 126, in pip_version_check
    headers={"Accept": "application/json"},
  File "c:\python365\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 521, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python365\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 386, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python365\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "c:\python365\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 640, in send
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "c:\python365\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 640, in <listcomp>
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "c:\python365\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 218, in resolve_redirects
    **adapter_kwargs
  File "c:\python365\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python365\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\adapter.py", line 47, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "c:\python365\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\adapters.py", line 440, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "c:\python365\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "c:\python365\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 346, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "c:\python365\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 850, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "c:\python365\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connection.py", line 284, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "c:\python365\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connection.py", line 141, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "c:\python365\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
```

Also, can't do `pip install --upgrade pip`
I tried many things like:

- disable IPV6
- delete VPN

I am out of ideas
I trying to figure this out for too long - please any help will do!

StackOverflow asking for more information but I'm totally lost so ignore this line.

Comment: problems with your internet is the reason for this error

Comment: Yes I can read... I have a valid internet connection that works. any suggestions on how to solve it would be great @KetZoomer